# Accsess denied for use .....@local host' (using password:NO)

Tags: mysql, c#, mvc, xampp

Estoy realizando un proyecto del instituto en C# pero tengo problemas cn la conexión a MySql
Al principio me habia quedado bien, agregué mas cosas al código y a la BD, al momento de realizar la prueba me aparece el siguiente mensaje :

Authentication to host 'localhost' for use 'Mi usuario de bd' using method  mysql_native_password failed with message: Accsess denied for use 'mi user @local host'  (using password:NO)

Este es el codigo de la clase conexión

```
    public static MySqlConnection getConexion()
   
        string servidor = "localhost";
        string puerto = "3306";
        string usuario = "Manu";
        string password = "12345";
        string bd = "sistema_usuario";

        string cadenaConexion = "server=" + servidor + "; port=" + puerto + "; user id=" + usuario + "; password="+password + "; database="+bd;

        MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);

        return conexion;
```

PDT: estoy utilizando Xampp

Comment: Estas seguro que esas son las credenciales de acceso, ese error aparece cuando estas intentando ingresar una password de conexion y en tu configuracion de acceeso en phpmyadmin esta configurado sin una password(password ="") o cuando es distinta de la ingresada, te sugiero que ingreses  a las configuraciones de tu phpmyadmin y revises las credenciales de acceso.

Comment: Y seguro que se escribe `user id=` con el espacio? Es muy raro ver un espacio en una cadena de este tipo

Comment: No es que no te creamos. Es sólo que ese `user id` nunca va a funcionar si uno revisa [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html).

Answer (score 0):

Si estas seguro que tus credenciales concuerdan con las que escribiste al momento de crear tu usuario y darle acceso a la base de datos creada, prueba entonces la conexión con el usuario root(que tiene privilegios de administrador total).

Puedes probar también con este ejemplo que esta en la web:

```
    using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace mysql
{
    class Program
    {
        private MySqlConnection conn;
        static void connect()
        {
            string server = "localhost";
            string database = "mysqldb1";
            string user = "root";
            string password = "u1s2e3r4";
            string port = "3306";
            string sslM = "none";

            string connString = String.Format("server={0};port={1};user id={2}; password={3}; database={4}; SslMode={5}", server, port, user, password, database, sslM);

            conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Connection Successful");

                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + connString);
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            connect();
        }
    }
}
```